# How to have a USB drive that always mounts to Z: on Windows on any computer

Tags: windows-10, usb-flash-drive

I need a USB drive that always mounts to the drive letter (Z:). The drive normally mounts to the next available mounts point. For example (D:), or if there is another drive already in (E:). I need it to always mounts to (Z:). Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can change the drive letter. It should use that from then on in the same PC.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia It needs to mount at the same letter in every computer right when I plug it in.

Comment: I don't know of any method to automate that.